# Can I see other user's badge progress and/or tag progress short of doing SEDE query?

Tags: support, profile-page, data-explorer, badge-progress

I can see my own badge/tag progress in the "Select your next badge" dialog box from the User Activity screen.  For example, I can see that I'm 455/500 for a gold Copy Editor badge in Christianity.SE.

Is there a way to see **another** user's badge/tag progress short of issuing an SE DataExplorer query?  If there is no way, can the answer provide a link to a SEDE query for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't see others' progress directly, except for the badge they're currently tracking - in your case, [Socratic on Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/10672/gratefuldisciple?tab=topactivity):

[image]

For some badges, it's indeed possible to track others' progress towards it through the Data Explorer, but the necessary query will vary widely depending on the badge, and for badges like Electorate it's (by design) not possible at all.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/867123/global-edit-summary) is a query I wrote to see how far a particular user is from the Copy Editor badge on *all* sites in the network. YMMV for other badges ...

Comment: I see that formulas for various badges would vary widely.  How about query for a tag?  Surely the data is open to the public and there are only 3 formulas (Bronze, Silver, Gold)?

Comment: I've never tried tracking those via SEDE; the tags page on user profiles, like https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=tags provides enough information (via tooltips) to see how close somebody is to gaining a tag badge. But that information should definitely be available via SEDE (if you don't mind it being a reflection of the situation last Sunday morning, instead of real-time)

Comment: Great, didn't realize that the Activity->Tags page contains the info I'm looking for (i.e. progress toward a badge).

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Additionally, you can find a list of top users for [any given tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/topusers). If you want a longer list, [you can use SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1778303/top-answerers-in-the-given-tag-including-deleted-users?num=100&tagName=discussion). (So here you can see the same information for several users at once - about the same tag.)